# Should I put assertions inside object's methods or writing and calling a check representation fuction is enough?t

Tags: testing, assert, assertions, assertion

I wonder if writing a check representation function for an object and calling it while testing is enough to check the object's internal state corectness or should I also put assertions inside methods? Or maybe I should only use assertions inside methods and just don't include them in production version to not slow my app down?